# Python discord.py - slash command doesn't show up in server

Tags: python, discord.py

I am try to write a discord bot with slash commands, the code can be onlined but the slash command doesn't show up on my discord channel/server. Below is my code on python

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="!",  # Change to desired prefix
    case_insensitive=True,  # Commands aren't case-sensitive
  intents=intents #intents
)

@bot.tree.command(name = "test", description = "My first application Command")
async def my_command(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
  await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id="xxx"))
  await interaction.response.send_message("Hello from my command!")

token = os.environ.get("discord_bot_key") 
bot.run(token)  # Starts the bot
```

my discord.py is 2.1.0

---

I have amended the code with per my understanding to the first answer:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="!",  
    case_insensitive=True,  
  intents=intents 
)

#Slash conmand starts
@bot.tree.command(name = "test", description = "My first application Command")
async def my_command(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
  await interaction.response.send_message("Hello from my command!")
#slash command ends

@bot.command()
async def synccmd(ctx):
  fmt = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
  await ctx.send(
    f"Syncd {len(fmt)} commands to the crrent server"
  )
  return

token = os.environ.get("discord_bot_key") 
bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sync your command tree using `tree.sync`. Slash commands are built-in into the Discord UI, so you have to let them know about your commands.

Do this in an **owner-only message command**. You're calling `sync` in a slash command, which doesn't make sense because you'd have to sync **that command** first before you can use it.

**Do not auto-sync in on-ready**! You will find this online, but this is terrible. The ratelimits are quite harsh, so if you spam it you won't be able to sync anymore.

Your current command would also sync every time it's used, which would get you ratelimited as well. You only have to sync once when you change something about your commands. If nothing is changed, there's no point in syncing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have amended the code but since still doesn't work, can you have a look? Thanks

Comment: When i called my message command, the bot returns me with "Syncd 0 commands to the crrent server"

Comment: That's a global command and you're syncing with a guild id only. Sync globally (don't pass an ID to `sync`) to sync global commands. **HOWEVER** during **development** (when you have to do this often) you can first use `copy_global_to` before `sync(dev_guild_id)` to copy your global commands to your dev guild. This makes development way faster and easier as guild-syncing is almost instant and global syncing can take a while.